When did Claude Navier write the work "Sur Les Lois du Mouvement des Fluides"?
When did Claude Navier write the work "Sur Les Lois du Mouvement des Fluides"?
I can’t find this information on the internet.
"Sur Les Lois du Mouvement des Fluides" read at 1822


I am confused. You give a date, 1822. What exactly do you mean by "written/introduced"?

@mdewey work/book can be published 20 years after idea was born/written/introduced.

Yes, I know that. Do you have a hypothesis that he wrote about it earlier than 1822 or that somebody may have attended a lecture he gave outlining the ideas?

@mdewey Navier-Stokes equations are introduced in 1821,(that also confirmed in my comments @ Conifold, so I just checking in wich work..

Actually, the memoir was read at the Académie des Sciences meeting on March 18, 1822, but was not published until five years later, in 1827.

@user6530 Do you know when was work written?

The work was conceived in 1821, it was read in 1822 and published in 1827, see Darrigol, The First Five Births of the Navier-Stokes Equation:"In 1821 Navier announced the general equations of equilibrium and motion for an (isotropic, one-constant) elastic body. He soon obtained the Navier-Stokes equation by transposing his reasoning to fluids." The date on your link is the date of the reading, not print publication.

@Conifold Isnt work "Sur les lois des mouvements des fluides, en ayant égard à l’adhésion des molecules"- memoire 1  conceived/written in 1821?                       Where do you find that "Sur Les Lois du Mouvement des Fluides" -memoire 2 conceived in 1821?

@user6530 Yes you are correct, 1822 was read. When is memoire written? Where can we find this information?

The "reading date", in this case, indicates the end of writing, through the publication process. He must bring the written text and read it to the Academy members. He must stand and defend before Laplace, Lagrange, Cauchy, and Legendre, among others, a feat that would truly terrify anyone. I describe below how it works.
The French Academy of Sciences, founded in 1666, was a leading institution for scientific advancement during the 19th century. Its rigorous processes for presenting, reviewing, and publishing scientific research helped establish standards for scientific communication and contributed significantly to the development of various scientific disciplines.
The text "MÉMOIRE SUR LES LOIS DU MOUVEMENT DES FLUIDES" by Claude-Louis Navier, presented to the French Academy of Sciences on March 18, 1822, was indeed read aloud during the session. This practice was common at the time, as scientific communications were often presented in person to the academy's members before being published.
The Publication Process in the French Academy of Sciences in the Early 19th Century
/
. **Presentation to the Academy (18/3/1822) **:

Scholars would prepare a detailed manuscript of their research, which would then be read aloud during a session of the academy. This could be done either by the author or by a designated presenter.
The presentation aimed to communicate the findings to the academy's members, facilitating immediate discussion and feedback.


**Review and Discussion (1823) **:

After the presentation, the members of the academy would discuss the merits and implications of the work. This peer-review-like process was informal but rigorous.
The feedback and critiques from esteemed members of the academy were crucial for the refinement of the work.


**Minutes and Reports **:

The proceedings of each session, including the discussions and conclusions about the presented works, were documented in the minutes of the academy. These minutes were often published in the "Comptes rendus de l'Académie des Sciences" (Proceedings of the Academy of Sciences).
This ensured a record of the scientific contributions and the academy's activities.


Publication in Journals or Memoirs (1827):

If the work was well-received, it could be published in the "Mémoires de l'Académie royale des Sciences" (Memoirs of the Royal Academy of Sciences), a prestigious journal that disseminated the research to a broader audience.
The publication process involved the preparation of a final manuscript, often incorporating feedback from the initial presentation and subsequent discussions.


Distribution:

Once published in the academy's journals or memoirs, the work would be accessible to the international scientific community. This facilitated further discussion, experimentation, and validation of the findings.



Example: Navier's Contribution
For Navier's work on the laws of fluid motion, the process would have likely included:

Preparation and Presentation: Navier prepared his findings and presented them to the academy on March 18, 1822.
Discussion: Members of the academy, including other prominent scientists, discuss his findings.
Documentation: The presentation and discussion would be documented in the academy's records.
Publication: Navier's memoir, once accepted, was published in the academy's official publications in volume 6, in 1827,  ensuring its dissemination and impact on the field of fluid mechanics.


You didnt write when work "Sur Les Lois du Mouvement des Fluides" is written. This is topic question.

Thanks! I'll try to clarify!

Do you know maybe answer for this question? https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/17649/is-navier-stokes-equations-first-time-derived-in-work-sur-les-lois-des-mouvemen
