Is Navier-Stokes equations first time derived in 1821. in work "Sur les lois des mouvements des fluides, en ayant égard à l’adhésion des molecules"?
Quote from this article, O. Darrigol, "Between Hydrodynamics and Elasticity Theory: The First Five Births of the Navier-Stokes Equation" (2002),Arch. Hist. Exact. Sci., page 114 :

The new equation of motion reads
$$\rho\left[\frac{\partial \mathbf v}{\partial t}+(\mathbf v\cdot\nabla)\mathbf v\right]=\mathbf f-\nabla P+\epsilon\Delta\mathbf v\tag{22}$$
It is known as the "Navier–Stokes equation."$^{35}$


Navier provided this equation in a memoir that was read on 18 March 1822 at the Academy of Sciences and published in summary form in the Annales de Chimie et de Physique


Above picture is this work..
1. Is Navier-Stokes equations first time derived in 1821. in work Sur les lois des mouvements des fluides, en ayant égard à l’adhésion des molecules  ?
2. Where I can find pdf of this work? (I find only this first page) I am interested if equations has viscous term  $\mu \nabla^2 u$ (don't have to be same notation)?

All volumes of Annales de Chimie et de Physique are available on Gallica. Here is a direct link to v.19, p.244. You can scroll and turn pages in the viewing window. There is pdf download on the sidebar, but it is buggy.

A Navier-Stokes equation does appear in

Navier, Sur les lois des mouvements des fluides, en ayant égard à l’adhésion des molecules, in Annales de chimie et de physique, vol XIX, Crochard, 1821.

In page 252 (Gallica link), Navier writes:
$$\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{dp}{dx}=X+\epsilon\left(3\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+\frac{d^2u}{dy^2}+\frac{d^2u}{dz^2}+2\frac{d^2v}{dxdy}+2\frac{d^2w}{dxdz}\right)-\frac{du}{dt}-\frac{du}{dx}u-\frac{du}{dy}v-\frac{du}{dz}w$$
$$\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{dp}{dy}=Y+\epsilon\left(\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}+3\frac{d^2v}{dy^2}+\frac{d^2v}{dz^2}+2\frac{d^2u}{dxdy}+2\frac{d^2w}{dydz}\right)-\frac{dv}{dt}-\frac{dv}{dx}u-\frac{dv}{dy}v-\frac{dv}{dz}w$$
$$\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{dp}{dz}=Z+\epsilon\left(\frac{d^2w}{dx^2}+\frac{d^2w}{dy^2}+3\frac{d^2w}{dz^2}+2\frac{d^2u}{dxdz}+2\frac{d^2v}{dydz}\right)-\frac{dw}{dt}-\frac{dw}{dx}u-\frac{dw}{dy}v-\frac{dw}{dz}w$$
which in modern notation [modulo a multiplicative factor of the density] reads
$$\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla p=\mathbf f+\epsilon\left[\nabla^2{\mathbf v} +2\nabla (\nabla\cdot\mathbf v)  \right]-\frac{\mathrm D\mathbf v}{\mathrm Dt}$$
using the continuity equation for incompressible fluids  $\nabla\cdot \mathbf v=0$ (also given by Navier in the same page) you can eliminate the term with prefactor 2 and get the modern Navier-Stokes equation for incompressible fluids and uniform viscosity.
Navier cites a previous work on elasticity for the viscosity term (with prefactor $\epsilon$):

Navier, Mémoire sur les Lois de l'Équilibre et du Mouvement des Corps Solides Élastique (14 May 1821), published in Mémoires de l'Académie de Sciences, vol. 7, published 1827   (Wikisource link)

As for the question if this is the first time that it appeared, some sources suggest it is (however I cannot abide to their veracity):

https://doi.org/10.1590/1806-9126-RBEF-2017-0239
https://doi.org/10.3390/fluids9010015

Most other articles cite 1822 (see for example G. A. Tokaty, A History and Philosophy of Fluid Mechanics, Dover). I think because they mixed it up with the time when Navier presented his equations to the Academy of Sciences, see

Navier, Mémoire sur les lois du mouvement des fluides (18 March 1822), Mémoires de l'Académie de Sciences vol 6, published 1827 (Wikisource link).

In 1822, there is however a small change (modern notation):
$$\mathbf f - \nabla p=\rho\frac{\mathrm D\mathbf v}{\mathrm Dt}-\epsilon\nabla^2{\mathbf v}$$
the factor $\rho$ now is correctly only applied to the material derivative, thus taking truly its modern form.

So we can say Navier-Stokes  equations are "born" in 1821?

@22flower sorry I am trying to check that, I think that in that work Navier cites another work of him on elasticity which might contain a similar equation

Goal of question is to find " year of  born"  for NS equations..That year will be engraved  on the statue. So I can't make a mistake..

@22flower I added more information, indeed some sources agree with this idea but I cannot find a high quality source. Darrigol source that you cited is more focused on 1821 elasticity work by Navier than by his fluid equation.

But NS equations that quote in your answer is from 1821

@22flower I added more information and why the 1822 version  is more modern. If I was writing a once-in-a-time masterpiece or so I would write 1821, but if for some reason I miswrote 1822 I would not mind.

I think work from 1822 is read in 1822 but is written in 1821 as well. There is difference between read and written("born").

@22flower help me out, what could help you here? To confirm if the 1822 is also from 1821? The first memoire from 1821 is that not enough?

Yes that is enough

Why in 1821 equation dont have ρ near  Dt/Dv? So is this version of equation correct?

@22flower the $\rho$ in the 1821 is ok, because $\epsilon$ is a constant so $\rho\epsilon$ is also a constant (it is the difference between absolute and kinematic viscosity). The forces also, in 1821 it is the forces per unit mass and in 1822 is per unit volume. Anyway both are correct but one has to correctly define the variables.
